# Why are there so many first posts right now?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

There are like 150 that need review, usually there are most 3 or 4 at a time.  Is this a bug?

Comment: They may have changed the criteria.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first post queue was bugged and no new questions were put into it for a while. I assume that these posts are the ones that were missed earlier due to the bug.

[From Nick Craver on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173895/151385):

> There was a bug by which [questions were not being added to the
>   queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173886/first-posts-review-queue-is-not-showing-first-questions),
>   that bug [was just
>   resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173892/135201) and the queue
>   got the items it should have had.